# How to read data from a binary file and write to a shared memory region?

Tags: c++, boost, file-io, shared-memory

I have created a shared memory region using boost. My next step is to read data from a binary file and write it to the shared memory region. I am using the following code to do this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("sigData.bin", ios::binary | ios::in); // file is of 1mb

    shared_memory_object shm(open_or_create, "shared_memory", read_write);

    shm.truncate(1024 * 1024);

    mapped_region region(shm, read_write);

    unsigned char * mem = static_cast<unsigned char*> (region.get_address());

    file.read(mem, region.get_size());
}
```

The above code gives me an error on the file.read() function. The error is as follows:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type* {aka char*}’ [-fpermissive]
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by casting the pointer from `unsigned char*` to `char*`; this is one of the rare cases where just changing the type of a pointer is OK.

So, use

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(mem), region.get_size());
```

Comment: So this wont temper the data or store signed char instead of unsigned char in the shared memory region?

Comment: @MobiZaman not 100% sure what you mean, but what it does is just changes the pointer type, nothing else.

Comment: What I meant was that I want my data to be read as unsigned data. If i change the pointer type to char, I still want my data to be read and stored as unsigned char. Based on your explanation, this should work, so I will try it.

Comment: the reading really just reads the bytes as they are. How you interpret this data is a completely different question, and unaffected by the signature of the `read` method :)